# Im having a permission related problem in google colab

Tags: python

I got a problem when i want to write info to my csv file

[This is the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXy1x.png)

my entire code is :

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np    
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
lokasiData = "drive/My Drive/Tubes Manli/used_cars.csv"
ds = pd.read_csv(lokasiData) #ds = data set
ds.head
ds.isnull().sum()
#2 Drop kolom county
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('county',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom size
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('size',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom url
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('url',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom region_url
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('region_url',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom image_url
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('image_url',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom description
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('description',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom vin
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('vin',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom state
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('state',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom lat
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('lat',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom long
ds.drop(ds.columns[ds.columns.str.contains('long',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData) 

# Drop kolom unnamed
ds.drop(ds.filter(regex="Unnamed"),axis=1, inplace=True)
ds.to_csv(lokasiData, index=False, sep=',')
```

[this is the picture of my colab explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUj2Q.png)

please help me, its a project in exchange for my final exam. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file from drive in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619189/read-file-from-drive-in-google-colab)

Comment: thanks but it is not

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the module required for mounting the google drive. 
And if using for the first time an authentication will be required.
 
After authentication and mounting up the drive use the following commands,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount(‘/content/drive/My Drive/Tubes Manli/used_cars.csv’)
```

And this should resolve the error.