# Colab notebook unable to find Google Sheets documents

Tags: python, google-sheets, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, gsheets

I have a set of documents stored in Google Drive that I am trying to read into dataframes in a Google Colab notebook but am receiving a `SpreadsheetNotFound` error.

I am following the steps outlined [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) and [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/sheets.ipynb) and am successful in mounting my Google drive. However, when I attempt to open a file connection, e.g.

```
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
df = gc.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/folder/worksheet.gsheets')
```

I receive an error saying that the spreadsheet is not found (the file appears in the list when I run `!ls /content/drive/MyDrive/folder`).

Is there a specific way that I should be referring to the document or drive that I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `openpyxl` instead of `gspread` and let us know if the problem still remains.

Comment: @SadraSabouri thanks—I've used openpyxl for excel spreadsheets but does it work for google sheets as well? I wasn't able to find any references in the documentation.

Comment: yes I suppose it will work. In worst case scenario you may wanted to convert it to excel and do the rest of it.
I also found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53623489/11587802) link which argues some odd things about Gsheets. I think the main reason for that error is the reading access block. I tried copying a `.gsheet` file from my drive to the `/content/` and I got `cp: cannot open '<filename>.gsheet' for reading: Operation not supported`

Comment: Update on this a few days later... I wasn't able to figure out the `.gsheet` issues and ended up writing to/calling from bigquery instead. Appreciate the suggestions @SadraSabouri